# Computer not very responsive

Tags: kernel, firefox, responsiveness

Sometimes, your computer may be slow to react - tasks take longer to finish, directories open slower, the kernel does not distribute the loads on the CPU cores very well...

Sometimes, this affects also Firefox, which is designed to run efficiently on multiple CPU cores.

Comment: Try opening a terminal window when it happens and run the `top` command. It's a process viewer for Linux. There will be a column called `%CPU` as well as `COMMAND`. Correlate the `%CPU` with the `COMMAND` and when the PC runs fast again, run the command again and see if it's there. When it runs slow again, try again the same thing and see if the same command is there again at 100% This will tell you if that's what causes the slow down of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can always try is:

```
sudo apt purge linux*
sudo apt install linux-image-generic
```

This will clean up system and kernel files which might affect performance.

Be aware that after `sudo apt purge linux*`, you cannot boot your computer anymore. Be sure to follow up with the second line.

Also, make absolutely sure you have a running internet connection - otherwise, `apt` cannot download the `linux-image-generic package`.

Comment: If you don't have internet running those two commands will break your system. Please be careful. If you don't have a laptop with uninterrupted internet, please think twice.